# C# The type or namespace name `List' could not be found. But I'm importing System.Collections.Generic;

Tags: c#, list, mono, monodevelop

I'm having an error

> The type or namespace name `List' could not be found. Are you missing
>   a using directive or an assembly reference?

Sample code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
public class city1 : MonoBehaviour 
{  
   public static List<string> items = new List ();
   public static List<double> itemsprice = new List();
   public static List<double> qu = new List();
}
```

I'm using mono if it matters.

Comment: Try `new List<string>();` instead of `new List();`. (and ...<double>, and so on).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The issue comes from your instantiation of `new List()`. These also need the generic component:

```
public static List<string> items = new List<string>();
public static List<double> itemsprice = new List<double>();
public static List<double> qu = new List<double>();
```

That is, there is no type `List` but there is a generic type `List<T>`.

More information and examples of instantiating the generic `List<T>` can be found in the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkbw11z0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: In my case I had to add `using System.Collections.Generic;`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

`public static List<string[]> items = new List<string>();`

Add brackets after string

Answer (score 1):

List is a generic type in Unity. You **should provide the item type while instantiating a List** in Unity.

```
List<type> list = new List<type>();
```

Ex:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
```

Change your list declaration as below,

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class city1 : MonoBehaviour 
{  
   public static List<string> items = new List<string>();
   public static List<double> itemsprice = new List<double>();
   public static List<double> qu = new List<double>();
}
```

For more: https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/lists-and-dictionaries#